# PHP read XML properties

Tags: php, xml, properties

I have the following XML data which is generated by a webservice

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<rsp xmlns="http://worldcat.org/xid/isbn/" stat="ok">
      <isbn   oclcnum="263710087 491996179 50279560 60857040 429386124 44597307" lccn="00131084" form="AA BC" year="2002" lang="eng" ed="1st American ed." title="Harry Potter and the goblet of fire"  author="J.K. Rowling."  publisher="Scholastic Inc."  city="New York [u.a.]"    url="http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/263710087?referer=xid">9780439139601</isbn>

</rsp>
```

I need to read the data in the 'isbn' tag, more specifically, the value of the property 'title'. How would I do this in PHP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this myself.

```
$xmldata= file_get_contents("http://xisbn.worldcat.org/webservices/xid/isbn/9780439139601?method=getMetadata&format=xml&fl=*");
$xml= new SimpleXMLElement($xmldata);
print $xml->isbn[0]['title'];
```

Comment: this depends on the number of isbn tags you have in your xml .. 
$xml->isbn[0]['title']; will only get you title for first isbn tag element.

I think you should use something like Gordon suggested.

Answer (score 4):

With [DOM](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('books.xml'); // or from URL    
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('isbn') as $node) {
    echo $node->getAttribute('title');
}
```

With [SimpleXml](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php):

```
$sxe = simplexml_load_file('filename.xml'); // or from URL
foreach($sxe->isbn as $node) {
    echo $node['title'];
}
```

Just my 2c why you want to use DOM: SimpleXML appears simple indeed, but simplicity in this case means lack of control. DOM isn't much harder to use and can do more. [DOM is an Interface Standard defined by the W3C](http://www.w3.org/DOM/) and can be found implemented in many languages, so it pays to know the API. True, it might be a bit more verbose than SimpleXML but it's also ultimately more powerful. If you have worked with DOM for some time, you don't want to go back.

Answer (score 0):

Using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.simplexml.php), or [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.dom.php).
Here are some usage examples : http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php