# how to get the values from this xml using dom in php?

Tags: php, xml

how can i get the values of `a,b and c` from the following xml code?

```
<result name="response" f="139" c="0">
−
<doc score="5.06756" pos="0">
<snippet name="a" highlighted="yes">example</snippet>
<snippet name="b" highlighted="yes">bexample</snippet>
<snippet name="c">cexample</snippet>


</doc>
</result>
```

I tried to print the nodes, but It failed:

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($content);

$x = $xmlDoc->documentElement;
foreach ($x->childNodes AS $item)
  {
  print $item->nodeName . " = " . $item->nodeValue . "<br />";
  }
```

Can anyone tell me how I can parse it? I cannot use simple xml, so I am moving to Dom.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression for grabbing the href attribute of an A element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/regular-expression-for-grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML lang parse in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996444/xmllang-parse-in-php/3996478#3996478)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract a node attribute from XML using PHP's DOM Parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993302/how-to-extract-a-node-attribute-from-xml-using-phps-dom-parser/3995983#3995983)

Comment: possible duplicate of [DOMDocument::load Getting attribute value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757587/domdocumentload-php-getting-attribute-value/4757670#4757670)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read XML properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085474/php-read-xml-properties/3085761#3085761)

Answer (score 1):

Using DOM allows you to use several distinct ways of extracting informations.

For example, you could work with :

- [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php), to extract all tags having a specific name.
- Or [`DOMXPath`](http://fr.php.net/domxpath), for more complex queries.

As an example, here's a portion of code that demonstrates how to use the first solution to extract all `` tags :

```
$snippets = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('snippet');
foreach ($snippets as $tag) {
  echo $tag->getAttribute('name') . ' = ' . $tag->nodeValue . '<br />';
}
```

And you'd get this output :

```
a = example
b = bexample
c = cexample
```

And, as another example, here's a solution that demonstrates how to use the second solution, to do a more complex query on the XML data -- here, extracting the `` tag that as it's `name` attribute with a value of `a` :

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlDoc);
$snippetsA = $xpath->query('//snippet[@name="a"]');
if ($snippetsA->length > 0) {
  foreach ($snippetsA as $tag) {
    echo $tag->getAttribute('name') . ' = ' . $tag->nodeValue . '<br />';
  }
}
```

Which only gets you one result -- the corresponding tag :

```
a = example
```

Starting from here, the possibilities are almost limitless ;-)